# Four vectors in three dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,V$ be two planes in $\mathbb R^3$ passing the origin. Show that their intersection $=:W$ (also a subspace) is at least one dimensional.

*Hint*: We have to show that $W$ contains a line, which is the case if it contains at leas one non-zero vector $ = \vec v$.

One possibility is as follows: Let $\vec a_1,\vec a_2$ be a basis in $U$ and $\vec b_1, \vec b_2$ be a basis in $V$. Show that we can find coefficients $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \mu_1, \mu_2,$ $\vec\lambda\neq\vec 0\neq\vec\mu$, such that $\lambda_1 + \vec a_1 +\lambda_2 \vec a_2 = \vec v = \mu_1\vec b_1 + \mu_2 \vec b_2$ in particular
$$\lambda_1 + \vec a_1 +\lambda_2 \vec a_2 - \mu_1\vec b_1 - \mu_2 \vec b_2 = \vec 0.$$

What can you say about the four vectors in three dimensions? ... Finish by explaining why we can fint nontrivial $\vec\lambda$ and $\vec\mu$.

What may I say about the four vectors in 3-D? Why exactly could we find nontrivial $\lambda$ and $\mu$?

Comment: Using the standard dimension formula in linear algebra dim($U + V$) $=$ dim ($U$) $+$ dim($V$) $-$ dim($U \cap V$), what can you conclude?

Comment: @SandeepThilakan Please consider posting that as a solution.

Comment: @SandeepThilakan In this case, assuming U, V meet at a line following the hint, I would know that dim (U and V) = 1. So dim(U+V) = 2 + 2 - 1 = 3.

Comment: Which means a1, a2, b1, b2 are linearly dependent! Number of vectors > number of vectors in basis of U and V ==> linearly dependent. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user124884 Well... that's kind of a foggy explanation. You know that $dim(U+V)\leq 3$, and that says that $2+2-dim(U\cap V)\leq 3$, and that says $1\leq dim(U\cap V)$.

Comment: @rschwieb Oh, since $dim$(U + V) doesn't have to be 3, it may also be 2. So dim(U and V) = dim(U) + dim(V) - dim(U+V) = 2 + 2 - dim(U+V). Since dim(U+V) <= 3 I will have dim(U and V) >= 1. Got it. Looking back, is the key to this question that dim(U+V) is either 2 or 3, less than the number of vectors (4) given?

Comment: @user124884 Yes, that's a better description :) The sum can't have less than $2$ dimensions because it contains a plane, but it has to fit in $\Bbb R^3$, so it can't have more than three dimensions. If we were working in $\Bbb R^4$ then *it is entirely possible for the intersection of two planes to be $0$ dimensional*, since the intersection could be $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the only way to combine the vectors $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2, \vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$ linearly to the zero vector is to choose $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\mu_1,\mu_2)=(0,0,0,0)$. This would mean that $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2, \vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$ are linearly independent, and their span $\mathcal M$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension $4$, so we conclude $4= \dim \mathcal{M}\leq\dim \mathbb{R}^3 =3,$ a contradiction. Thus $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2, \vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$ are not linearly independent, and there is a nontrivial choice of $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\mu_1,\mu_2)$ such that the linear combination is zero.

It remains to see that this choice is not only nontrivial, but also leads to notrivial $\vec{\lambda}$ and $\vec{\mu}$: Suppose that both $\lambda$s are equal to zero. Then the equation states that there a nontrivial linear combination of $\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$ to the zero vector, which is not possible, since $\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$ is a basis of $V$. Similarly, assuming a trivial $\vec{\mu}$ contradicts the fact that $\vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2$ is a basis of $U$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find these nontrivial coeffs because four vectors in a three-dimensional vectorspace are always dependent, ie there exists a nontrivial linear combination which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

dim($U$) = dim($V$) $= 2$. Further $3 \geq $dim($U + V$) $\geq 2$. Using dimension formula, dim($U + V$) = dim($U$) + dim($V$) - dim($U \cap V$), we get $1 \leq$ dim($U \cap V$) $\leq 2$.